# ELK for windows logs processing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, event-log, kibana

I've made a working ELK stack on Debian Wheezy and have set up Nxlog to gather windows logs. I see the logs in Kibana - everything is working fine, but i get too much data and want to filter it by removing some fields that I don't need.

I've made a filter section but it's not working at all. What can be the reason? 
The filter above

```
input {
tcp {
    type   => "eventlog"
    port   => 3515
    format => "json"
        }
}
filter {
    type => "eventlog"
   mutate {
           remove => { "Hostname",  "Keywords", "SeverityValue", "Severity", "SourceName", "ProviderGuid" }
           remove => { "Version", "Task", "OpcodeValue", "RecordNumber", "ProcessID", "ThreadID", "Channel" }
           remove => { "Category", "Opcode", "SubjectUserSid", "SubjectUserName",  "SubjectDomainName" }
           remove => { "SubjectLogonId", "ObjectType", "IpPort", "AccessMask", "AccessList", "AccessReason" }
           remove => { "EventReceivedTime", "SourceModuleName", "SourceModuleType", "@version", "type" }
           remove => { "_index", "_type", "_id", "_score", "_source", "KeyLength", "TargetUserSid" }
           remove => { "TargetDomainName", "TargetLogonId", "LogonType", "LogonProcessName", "AuthenticationPackageName" }
           remove => { "LogonGuid", "TransmittedServices", "LmPackageName", "ProcessName", "ImpersonationLevel" }
           }
    } 
output {
elasticsearch {
    cluster => "wisp"
    node_name => "io"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to remove fields that do not exist in some logs.
Does all your logs contains all the fieds you're trying to remove ?
If not, you have to identify your logs before removing fields.
Your filter config will look like this :

```
filter {
    type => "eventlog"
    if [somefield] == "somevalue" {
        mutate {
            remove => { "specificfieldtoremove1", "specificfieldtoremove2" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was that **remove** directive is no longer supported, and everything worked when i used **remove_field** instead

Comment: I didn't notice that you were not using **remove_field** directive. But yes, there is no **remove** directive anymore. Good to know that everything works fine.